# How to recover from onApplicationConnectionFailed() - errorCode = 8, INTERNAL_ERROR?

Tags: google-cast

I have a network where spurious cast heartbeat failures occur.  Sometimes this happens during the launch of the receiver application.  Here is debug from my app:

`08-28 21:38:53.308  10495-10495/com.bannerstonesoftware.XYZ D/CastedTournament﹕ onConnected()
08-28 21:38:53.471  10495-10495/com.bannerstonesoftware.XYZ D/CastedTournament﹕ onApplicationStatusChanged() - appStatus:
08-28 21:38:53.675  10495-10495/com.bannerstonesoftware.XYZ D/CastedTournament﹕ onApplicationStatusChanged() - appStatus:null
08-28 21:39:13.382  10495-10495/com.bannerstonesoftware.XYZ D/CastedTournament﹕ onConnectionSuspended(), cause = 2
08-28 21:39:13.383  10495-10495/com.bannerstonesoftware.XYZ D/CastedTournament﹕ onDisconnected()
08-28 21:39:13.384  10495-10495/com.bannerstonesoftware.XYZ D/CastedTournament﹕ onApplicationConnectionFailed() - errorCode:8
08-28 21:39:15.091  10495-10495/com.bannerstonesoftware.XYZ D/CastedTournament﹕ onConnectivityRecovered()`

After seeing 'onConnectivityRecovered' I tried calling 'sendDataMessage()' on the DataCastManager, but get a 'NoConnectionException' from the CCL (I tried it both with and without first calling 'reconnectSessionIfPossible()').  The cast icon shows as being connected.  If I choose to stop casting via the cast menu my cast receiver will still be shown on the TV.  And, then on reconnection via the cast menu the application launch quickly completes.

Questions:

- Why didn't the cast icon show as being unconnected after the receiver app failed to launch?  Intended design?
- If intended design should I simply turn around and call 'disconnectDevice()' on the DataCastManager?
- Is it expected that onConnectivityRecovered() get called in this scenario?

Broadly speaking, what are my recovery options?

Comment: Please open a ticket on the CCL's github project, I can have you test a few things to see if that addresses your issue. In general, when onApplicationConnectionFailed() is called, you should see the cast icon showing disconnected (so I believe it is a bug in DataCastManager).

Comment: https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/issues/203